# Text Classification using keras, can we directly train on document term matrix?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to do Text Classification using keras, I have preprocessed the text properly removed stopwords, stemmed them, removed punctuation, created Document Term Matrix, The part where i am confused is can i use DTM to directly train my model ?
I am getting a very weird error that i am not able to get through

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() 
  model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(784)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = 'softmax')

model %>% compile(
  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  dtm_train_most_frequent, train_labels, 
  epochs = 30, batch_size = 128, 
  validation_split = 0.2
)
```

The error i am getting is

```
Error in UseMethod("fit") : 
  no applicable method for 'fit' applied to an object of class "c('keras.engine.sequential.Sequential', 'keras.engine.training.Model', 'keras.engine.network.Network', 'keras.engine.base_layer.Layer', 'python.builtin.object')"
```

I am using R

Comment: What error do you get? Are you using Python or r?

Comment: i am using r language

Comment: Error in UseMethod("fit") : 
  no applicable method for 'fit' applied to an object of class "c('keras.engine.sequential.Sequential', 'keras.engine.training.Model', 'keras.engine.network.Network', 'keras.engine.base_layer.Layer', 'python.builtin.object')"

Answer (score 3):

Please write `fit` function in the following form:

```
keras::fit()
```

Comment: You are a gentle-person and a scholar!  Thanks this worked great!